# FFMPEG and AWS Mountpoint random write output error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I'm testing the new feature in AWS with mountpoint-s3 to read and write directly to S3 the video files to encode. I've crossed a problem with random writes with the output that is not supported.

This is the error:

```
mountpoint_s3::fuse: write failed: upload error: out of order write; expected offset 3461864 but got 36
```

This was discussed with the people that created mountpoint on github and they asked me:

```
Is there any way your ffmpeg workload can be configured to not require random write access to the files?
```

Does anyone know any command that could force FFMPEG to avoid any random write?

This is my command at the moment:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -map 0:a:1 -metadata language=ENG -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000K -minrate 5000K -maxrate 5000K -bufsize 6000K -g 12 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -r 30000/1001 -profile:v main422-10 -level 4.1 -aspect 16:9 -x265-params no-scenecut:open-gop:min-keyint=72:keyint=72:-colorprim=bt709 -vf "scale=1920:-1" -c:a aac -ar 48000 -rematrix_maxval 1.0 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -y outputfile
```

Comment: What is the output format you're using?  mp4 files can't be created without seeking, you might consider using a format like matroska, which does not require seeking after creation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.